# Pre-populate form using React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm pretty new to React and wasn't able to solve this issue. I'm trying to pre-populate a form with information fetched from the database using a parent component. The child component is supposed to show the data as the default and then change states when the user edits the form. 
This is how I pass the data as props (Edit 2):

```
componentDidMount() {
    const ticketID = this.props.match.params.ticketID;
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tickets/${ticketID}`).then(res => {
      this.setState({ ticket: res.data }, () => console.log(this.state.ticket));
    });
  }

{this.state && this.state.ticket ? (
  <TicketForm
    requestType="put"
    ticketID={this.props.match.params.ticketID}
    btnText="Update"
    ticket={this.state.ticket}
    />
 ) : (
  <div />
    )}
```

This works fine. I'm able to get the data and console.log it, but I'm unable to set it to be the default state. The form remains blank and when I try to type something on it throws the warning: "A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa)". <--- Solved (Edit 2)

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IK9k9hSuYeA&t=373s.

Child component is as follows:

```
class TicketForm extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: props.ticket.name || "",
      description: props.ticket.description || ""

    };

    handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
    }; 

    (...)


   render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <div className="card mb-3">
          <div className="card-header">
            <h2>{this.state.btnText} Ticket</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <form
              onSubmit={e =>
                this.onSubmit(e, this.props.requestType, this.props.ticketID)
              }
            >
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  placeholder="Ticket name"
                  value={this.state.name} 
                  onChange={e => {
                    this.handleChange(e);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                <textarea
                  name="description"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  rows="3"
                  placeholder="Ticket Description"
                  value={this.state.description}
                  onChange={e => {
                    this.handleChange(e);
                  }}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
             (...)

)}
```

I spent hours trying to fix this and read a bunch of posts on here, but still wasn't able to solve this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit 1: I finally figured out why props is undefined on the constructor. When I pass ticket as props, ticket is still being fetched from the database, so the value received by the constructor is still undefined.

Edit 2: Tried using ternary operator on the parent child to make sure props were only passed on after state was fully set.

Answer (score 1):

This error should only occur if the initial state for `name` or `description` is undefined, which you're not checking for in your code.

Try changing your constructor to:

```
   constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: props.ticket.name || '',
      description: props.ticket.description || '',

    };
```

This way, if you have an `undefined` value for either of them, you still set an empty string as a fallback value.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The warning is gone. I had tried something similar before, but I guess the main issue here is the form is still not pre-populated. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to call `super()` with props as an argument: `super(props)`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);  // <-- instead of super()
  this.state = {
    name: props.ticket.name,
    description: props.ticket.description
  };

  ...
}
```

I'm not sure that makes a difference, it would seem that `this.state.ticket` passed before is not being set correctly. Can you try `console.log(this.state.ticket)` and see if it is indeed an object of the form `{name: ..., description: ...}`?

Comment: I changed props and it didn't make any difference.  The thing is when I console.log(this.state.ticket) while on the parent component, it takes quite a while for it to print the actual ticket object (it prints undefined first). So I tried to use a ternary operator to only pass on props after the state is set, but it doesn't seem to work. I'll update my question to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: You should understand the basics of state and props before you deep dive. When you initialize a state in a constructor, it is only initialized once. React has no way to update the component state based on props. So, in order to achieve this, they provided a hook `getDerivedStateFromProps` as the name suggests to derive the state from props. Hope it helps you to clear your queries.

On the other note, I would encourage you to start with React Hooks rather than class components as these errors can be easily handled using `useEffect` in functional components. I hope I am able to give you a better overview. Let me know if you still find any difficulties.

```
class TicketForm extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      description: ""

    };

   static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) { 
    // Stringify as to check ticket is an object. In case it is a string
    // or integer you can directly, check the equality
    if (JSON.stringify(props.ticket) !== JSON.stringify(state)) {
     return {
      name: props.ticket.name,
      description: props.ticket.description
     }
    }
    return null;
   }

    handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
    }; 

    (...)


   render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <div className="card mb-3">
          <div className="card-header">
            <h2>{this.state.btnText} Ticket</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <form
              onSubmit={e =>
                this.onSubmit(e, this.props.requestType, this.props.ticketID)
              }
            >
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  placeholder="Ticket name"
                  value={this.state.name} 
                  onChange={e => {
                    this.handleChange(e);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                <textarea
                  name="description"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  rows="3"
                  placeholder="Ticket Description"
                  value={this.state.description}
                  onChange={e => {
                    this.handleChange(e);
                  }}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
             (...)

)}
```